# Project Euler #29 in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement a solution to the following problem:
For a in [1,100] and b in [1,100], do a^b for every a and b. How many unique results we can obtain?

In Python I can solve this problem and I get the correct answer, but when I try a R implementation I can't get the correct answer.

Here's my code:

```
lista=c()
for (b in 2:100){
  for (a in 2:100){
    elemento=a^b
    if (!is.element(elemento,lista)){
      lista=c(lista,elemento)
    }
  }
}


print(length(lista))
```

Answer (score 4):

Hmm.  I get the same answer as you do (although much faster).

```
length(unique(sort(c(outer(2:100,2:100,"^")))))
## 9183
```

According to [the problem statement](http://projecteuler.net/problem=29), your code (starting at 2) rather than your description (starting at 1) is correct ...

I stole [a Python solution](http://zacharydenton.com/project-euler-solutions/29/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
print len(set(a**b for a,b in itertools.product(range(2,101), repeat=2)))
```

which gave me the same answer (9183) [Python's `range(m,n)` function appears to give values from `m` to `n-1` inclusive, unlike R's `seq()` shortcut `:` which gives an inclusive sequence from `m` to `n`]

**Update**: it's been pointed out that R is doing inexact floating-point calculations for the big numbers -- Python might be too.  We can do this with the `gmp` package, but things have to be done a little more carefully ...

```
library("gmp")
v <- as.bigz(2:100)
uu <- do.call("c",sapply(v,function(x) x^v))
length(unique(uu))  ## 9183 again
```

Comment: That's the correct answer, but I'd say there is a bit of luck in getting it. Although you pass integers to `outer`, it returns a matrix of numerics... Also note how 100^100 is greater than `.Machine$integer.max`. If OP wants to take on Project Euler seriously, he will have to build a library for large integers. Which he will be able to re-use and improve as he gets into the harder problems.

Comment: @flodel You are right and the package `gmp` can help in that case

Comment: @flodel, good point. I was going to suggest the `bit64` package, but that (64-bit integers) only takes us up to 2^62 ...

Comment: well, that would be cheating! Also, I take something I said back: it is not `outer` that returns a numeric, but `^` which I find a bit strange (see `class(1L^1L)` for example)

Comment: I don't know about cheating.  What are the rules about using packages?  The Python solution I copied uses `itertools` ...

Answer (score 3):

The most R'ish way to do that is ot use `outer` just like @BenBolker did, it's much more faster.

Now if for any reason you want to stick with the basic brute force algorithm using nested for loops (very slow), here is one way

```
res <- vector(mode = "numeric")
for (a in 2:100) {
    for (b in 2:100) {
        tmp <- a^b
      if (!is.element(tmp, res))
          res <- append(res, tmp)
    }
}

length(res)
## [1] 9183


res <- sort(res)
res2 <- sort(unique(c(outer(2:100, 2:100, "^"))))
all.equal(res, res2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
euler <-  unique(unlist(lapply(2:100, FUN = function(x) x^c(2:100))))

> length(euler)
[1] 9183
```

Comment: Why does your answer give a different number than the other answers?

Comment: @GSee they changed it to go from 2:100 instead of 1:100

Comment: As I said in my answer below, there's a mismatch between the original problem statement and the problem as stated by the OP ...